# how to use "IO actions" with list comprehension or mapper in Rascal?

Tags: list, io, rascal

I was wondering that IO actions (like println) would return a value of type void, and then we could use these actions in a list comprehension or as argument to the mapper function. However, when I try

```
rascal> import IO;
rascal> import List; 
rascal> [println(x) | x <- [1,2,3]];
```

I got a null pointer exception (part of the stacktrace bellow). The same occurs when I try

```
rascal> mapper([1,2,3], println);
1
java.lang.NullPointerException(internal error) at $root$(|main://$root$|)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.usethesource.vallang.impl.fast.ListWriter.updateType(ListWriter.java:76)
    at io.usethesource.vallang.impl.fast.ListWriter.append(ListWriter.java:84)
    at org.rascalmpl.semantics.dynamic.ListComprehensionWriter.append(ListComprehensionWriter.java:38)
```

Surely, I was not really expecting a behaviour like mapping an IO action into a list in Haskell, though I do not understand the reason for this null pointer exception in Rascal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the null pointer is that `printf` is a void function. In the current implementation this is implemented as a `null` pointer. You could use instead

```
for(x <- [1,2,3]) println(x);
```

Comment: I wonder: would it make sense to report a type error in this case?

Comment: Yes. Its a bug! You can use bprintln to work around. It always returns true

Comment: @RodrigoBonifacio: yes you are completely right this has to be reported as a type error.